# Is the remaining code of a function that comes after a Future processed in "one batch" on the event queue?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, event-loop

I thought that when the compiler hits a future, automatically the future and the remaining code of the function is placed on the event queue and bundled up as one future basically.
So in this example from Future1 to somebullshit() everything should be pushed on the event queue and the future returned from asyncFunction() should resolve when everything is processed.

```
main(){
     asyncFunction()
}
asyncFunction() async{
     await Future1();
     await Future2();
     somebullshit();
}
```

- My experience was that after Future1 is completed on the event queue
  not Future2 is processed next but some createState Method from the
  framework is called first and then it continues to Future2.
- So why is it not processed directly one after another?
- And why if I wrap my asyncFunction inside a Future like this, does the code work as expected and executes everything in one batch after the createState method is called

```
main(){
    Future((){asyncFunction() })
}
```

Is the explanation that just like with synchronous code the compiler automatically jumps out of the current function when hitting a future even when its handled on the event loop and first processes something else?

Answer (score 0):

Ok my problem was that I didn't return anything inside the function in the Future constructor my bad.

```
  await Future(() {
  return someAsyncStuff();
});
```